# Jackson JSON API Deserialization Streaming Unrecognized Field

Tags: java, jackson

I have this json:

```
[{"cdCondicaoPagto":"1","NrParcela":1,"NrDias":0}]
```

and this class:

```
public static class CondicaoPagtoItem implements Serializable {

    private String cdCondicaoPagto;
    private Integer NrParcela;
    private Integer NrDias;

    public CondicaoPagtoItem() {
    }

    public String getCdCondicaoPagto() {
        return cdCondicaoPagto;
    }

    public void setCdCondicaoPagto(String cdCondicaoPagto) {
        this.cdCondicaoPagto = cdCondicaoPagto;
    }

    public Integer getNrParcela() {
        return NrParcela;
    }

    public void setNrParcela(Integer NrParcela) {
        this.NrParcela = NrParcela;
    }

    public Integer getNrDias() {
        return NrDias;
    }

    public void setNrDias(Integer NrDias) {
        this.NrDias = NrDias;
    }
}
```

And I'm trying to read it by streaming, this way:

```
JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JsonFactory();
ObjectMapper jsonMapper = new ObjectMapper(jsonFactory);
JsonNode jsonNodeGeral = jsonMapper.readTree(new File("/home/cechinel/Documentos/CondicaoPagtoItem.json"));  

Iterator<JsonNode> elements = jsonNodeGeral.getElements();

while(elements.hasNext()){
    JsonNode jsonNode = elements.next();

    CondicaoPagtoItem condicao = jsonMapper.treeToValue(jsonNode, CondicaoPagtoItem.class);
}
```

But It causing the following error:

> UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "NrParcela"

If I use the annotation @JsonProperty it works, but I don't want to do it in which integer field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds to me more like it's a naming convention mismatch.  `setNrParcela` would map to a field name `nrParcela` but your JSON document has the 'n' capitalized as `NrParcela`.

If you cannot change the JSON field capitalization, you can use `@JsonProperty` with an overridden name:

```
@JsonProperty("NrParcela")
```

But since you didn't want to do that, another option to consider is implementing a [PropertyNamingStrategy](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeaturePropertyNamingStrategy).

Comment: Omg. I don't believe I didn't see that kkk. Thank you. It works ^^